# JSON undefined error using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My Javascript alert's undefined when trying to read the following JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "number_messages":"3"
    },
    {
        "message1":"abc"
    },
    {
        "message2":"c"
    },
    {
        "message3":"a"
    }
]
```

I am using AJAX to get this string (it gets trough correctly.

```
resp=jQuery.parseJSON(response);
alert( resp.number_messages );
```

My ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({  
type: 'POST',  
url: 'backend2.php',  
data: dataString,
success: submitFinished,
dataType: 'json'
});
```

This alerts "undefined", no errors show up in dragonfly (it's like firebug but for opera).

I am quite new to the whole JSON JQuery thing, so it's prob. something really easy, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've searched for answers and edited my code for over an hour, and still haven't got it to work.

Comment: Where's `response` coming from? Chances are it doesn't contain the JSON string, but a response object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791356/converting-multiline-indented-json-to-single-line-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert( resp[0].number_messages );
```

Comment: You do see why that worked, right?  It's because you have an array of structures (so you'll have to address each of the other elements with the appropriate index).

Comment: Yes, it's all clear now. Had been trying with .each because I figured it might be an array but didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery automatically parses json data into an object, you dont need jQuery.parseJSON(response)

```
$.ajax({
  "url":"page.php",
  "dataType":"json",
  "success":function(data){
    alert(data[0].number_messages);
  }
});
```